# I wanna publish a integer from potentiometer using a ADS1115 module value to control a led with a ros2 python publishersubscriber node

Tags: ros2, python

i need to publish a integer from a ros2 talker node with a ads1115 to control a led in a listener node in python like this :

```
import time 
import rclpy from rclpy.node 
import Node from time import sleep 
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int32 #now setup circuitpython gpio import board 
import busio

#now activate ads1115 for the knob
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in 
import AnalogIn 
from adafruit_simplemath import map_range # make the map function working.

Create the I2C bus
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

Create the ADC object using the I2C bus
ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)

Create single-ended input on channel 0
chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

#chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0, ADS.P1) 
pot = int(map_range(chan.value,0,1020,0,100))#is the mapped value of a potentiometer.

class Adctalk(Node): 
def init(self): 
super().init('adctopic') 
self.publisher_= self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10) 
self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10) # is the int that need to be 
    timer_period = 0.5
    self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
    self.i = 0

def timer_callback(self):

   
   
    msg = String() 
   
    Adcmsg = Int32() # should turn to a int.
    msg.data= 'adc channel: %d'  % self.i 
    Adcmsg.data= pot
 
  
    self.publisher_.publish(msg)
    self.Adcpub_.publish(Adcmsg.data) # should publish pot value in data
    self.get_logger().info(msg.data) # logs string
    
    self.get_logger().info( Adcmsg.data) # logs pot value
    
    
   
    self.i += 1
def main(args=None): rclpy.init(args=args)
adctalk = Adctalk()
rclpy.spin(adctalk)
adctalk.destroy_node
rclpy.shutdown()
if name == 'main': main()
```

and receiving it in a node listener node:

```
import rclpy from rclpy.node import Node
from time import sleep from std_msgs.msg import String 
import time 
#now setup circuitpython gpio 
import board 
import digitalio

print("hello blinka!")

led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D4) # is the led pin led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT


class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('adctopic')
    self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
        String,
        'topic',
        self.listener_callback,
        10)
    self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

def listener_callback(self, msg,Adcmsg):
    self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)
    self.get_logger().info('I Adcvalue  i see is : "%s"' % Adcmsg)
    led.value  = Adcmsg # led value is equql to the Adsmsg data. 
   
    
def main(args=None): rclpy.init(args=args)

minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()

rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

# Destroy the node explicitly
# (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
# when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
rclpy.shutdown()
if name == 'main': 
main()
```

but now it supposed to blink equal to the Adcmsg value. but it gives a error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/pyeng_adcpubsub/talk", line 33, in sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyeng-adcpubsub==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'talk')()) File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 60, in main adctalk = Adctalk() File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 30, in init self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10) File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1469, in create_publisher final_topic = self.resolve_topic_name(topic) File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1422, in resolve_topic_name return _rclpy.rclpy_resolve_name(self.handle, topic, only_expand, False) TypeError: rclpy_resolve_name(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (arg0: rclpy::Node, arg1: str, arg2: bool, arg3: bool) -> str

Invoked with: <rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.Node object at 0xffff9596c5f0>, 0, False, False [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your error. What does it say?

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/pyeng_adcpubsub/talk", line 33, in sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyeng-adcpubsub==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'talk')()) File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 60, in main adctalk = Adctalk() File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 30, in init self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10) File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1469, in create_publisher final_topic = self.resolve_topic_name(topic) File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1422, in resolve_topic_name return _rclpy.rclpy_resolve_name(self.handle, topic, only_expand, False) TypeError: rclpy_resolve_name(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (arg0: rclpy::Node, arg1: str, arg2: bool, arg3: bool) -> str

That's a lot. This is called a "call stack," so it's showing you all the function calls that got it to the point of having and error. After the call stack it gives you the error. Let's look at the error so we know what to look for in the call stack. Your error is:

```
TypeError: rclpy_resolve_name(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (arg0: rclpy::Node, arg1: str, arg2: bool, arg3: bool) -> str
```

So, it's something wrong with the way you've passed arguments to a function.

Look through your error stack one file at a time. Where did the problem start? First it called this file:

> File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/pyeng_adcpubsub/talk"

on this line:

> line 33,

and there was a problem when it called this function:

> sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyeng-adcpubsub==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'talk')())

That does not look like it could be our error. So, once it called that method, what was the problem? We have to move on to the next entry in the call stack:

> File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py"

on this line:

> line 60,

and there was a problem when it called this function:

> main adctalk = Adctalk()

That *also* does not look like our error. So, we move on to the third call in the stack:

> File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py"

on this line:

> line 30,

and there was a problem when it called this function:

> init self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10)

ahhhh this looks like it. What should the arguments to `create_publisher` be? [From the documentation](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclpy/api/node.html#rclpy.node.Node.create_publisher), it looks like the second argument here should be the topic, as a string. You've given the second argument to be `pot`, which you defined in your code as:

```
pot = int(map_range(chan.value,0,1020,0,100))#is the mapped value of a potentiometer.
```

If we keep looking down the call stack for the error, the next function that has trouble is:

> self.resolve_topic_name(topic)

and you can see here that it's throwing the error when it tries to resolve your topic name, because you have given it an `int` as a topic when it's expecting a `str`.

So, we looked at each point in the call stack the error gave us to find where the problem is! The problem is that you should create your `Adcpub_` like so:

```
self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32, 'pot', 10) # is the int that need to be
```

(or use a topic other than `'pot'` if you want a different topic name.)

Comment: i got the value send over from publisher to subscriber but the led doesnt  blink from the the value from the Adcmsg.data

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Jonathan Dawsa. If you've got a related question, please start a new question. At a glance, it looks like you're driving a **digital** pin (ON/OFF) with an analog value, which would be 0 = Off and anything else = On. You may want to use [pwmio](https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/pwmio/index.html) instead, but again, please start a new question and ask specifically and then everyone on the site has a chance to ask clarifying questions and give answers!